# Vue.js with mocha and styles-resources-loader can't load dependency sass

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, vuejs2, mochapack

I have the problem that mochapack does not seem to work together with the style resources loader.

packages that seem to produce the problem:

- "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "~4.2.0",
- "vue-cli-plugin-style-resources-loader": "~0.1.4"

My `vue.config.js` file:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  ...

  pluginOptions: {
    "style-resources-loader": {
      preProcessor: "scss",
      patterns: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/assets/styles/*.scss")]
    }
  }
};
```

The single sass file that is included through the above config:

```
@import "~vue-select/src/scss/vue-select.scss";
```

It seems to load the `vue-select.scss` correctly but then when interpreting this file it seems to loose its current directory and does not find the imported style.

Error log excerpt:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import "global/variables";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  /node_modules/vue-select/src/scss/vue-select.scss 1:9  @import
  /src/components/HelloWorld.vue 1:9
```

See full detail error message and code:
https://github.com/petritz/food-calculator-web/runs/560575367

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?
I am getting the same unit test error.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Mocha for my Unit Tests. After having the same issue, I noticed that I had to change my `vue.config.js` from:

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: "/",
  css: {
    sourceMap: true,
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: `@import "@/scss/main.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
};
```

to:

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: "/",
  css: {
    sourceMap: true,
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import "@/scss/main.scss";`
      }
    }
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    if (
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "test" ||
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ) {
      const scssRule = config.module.rule("scss");
      scssRule.uses.clear();
      scssRule.use("null-loader").loader("null-loader");
    }
  }
};
```

**EDIT:** This might have some issues with local dev and production, so I had to change a couple of things:

- I upgraded the `sass-loader` to at least 10.1.0
- I had to install the `null-loader` to work around with CSS Preprocessor modules
- I had to use `chainWebpack` in the `vue.config.js` to use the `null-loader` in my `test` and `production` environments

I found the answer in this open issue on the Vue CLI GitHub repo: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4053#issuecomment-544641072

Comment: This worked wonders for me. It's very unexpected that the null-loader suddenly fixes the issue. Can you help me understand why this is the case?

Comment: @ekampp because your styles are just ignored. This is not all that great of a solution

Comment: @heap1, my styles are being parsed and processed and works with this solution. So not completely ignored. I think there's more to it than this.

Comment: @ekampp no, your styles are replaced with empty content. So it may seem like they are getting loaded, but they're not really. For example if you had a css class that sets content, then try checking in your test suite if the html contains the content. It will not, because the css is discarded in place of empty content

Comment: ^ if the above test results in your html actually containing the content, it is because your styles are embedded with the html and your css is not served seperately